# USB Image Mounting Executable

Tags: mount, usb-flash-drive, disk-image

So I've used Daemon tools before to mount ISO images but I was wondering if anyone knows of a lightweight IOS mounter executable that I can put on a thumbdrive and run from any windows device without having to install it.

The goal is to stick several CD's of data onto an external hard drive or large usb drive and be able to access the data as if it were a CD on any Windows machine.

Comment: I think it is pretty unlikely that you could find a portable app to do this.  It requires a driver install, there is no built-in facility in windows.

Comment: Product recommendations, including if-exists recon, are off topic per the [faq](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Zoredache said in his comment, you're not going to find a portable image mounting app because it requires system level access to install a driver for the virtual optical drive.  The closest you're going to get is just having a portable archiving utility like 7-zip that can extract the contents of your ISOs to wherever you need.

Alternatively, you can pre-extract those ISOs onto your portable drive and just access the data from the drive directly.